# FreeBSD + SSSD + Samba + Windos Server 2019 AD: Unable to set permissions or create files

Tags: freebsd, active-directory, sssd, samba4

I'm using:

- FreeBSD 12.1 release p10 amb64
- Samba 4.10.17
- sssd 1.11.7

I'm about to upgrade Active Directory from Windows 2012R2 to Windows 2019. In my existing setup, I have the unix attributes added to the 2012 AD and use Winbind to integrate with AD.

In my new setup, I'm trying to use SSSD + Samba to integrate with AD, without using unix attributes. I've been able to set up SSSD and connect to AD. I've modified both PAM and NSSwitch so that I can log in as AD users, and query AD users as if they were local.

I have a test share that points to a ZFS Zvol that has both aclmode and aclinherit set to passthrough. I'm only able to get user accounts to work properly; settings group ACLs does not seem to grant access.

When I set ACLs using setfacl, it works correctly on both BSD and Windows servers. On the Windows side, if I look at the properties->security tab, the users show up as "user-name [Unix User\user-name]" as apposed to "full name [user-name@domain.com]" in my Windows 2012R2 setup.

I've been unable to find anything useful in the logs. I'm unable to discover what the problem is, but believe that both the group/acl problem and Windows/Samba not recognizing user/groups set as AD users instead of Unix users are both symptoms of the problem.

**krb5.conf**

```
[libdefaults]
default_realm = DERP.WHATEVER.COM
dns_lookup_realm = true
dns_lookup_kdc = true
ticket_lifetime = 24h
renew_lifetime = 7d
forwardable = true
rdns = false
default_tgs_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96 RC4-HMAC DES-CBC-CRC DES-CBC-MD5
default_tkt_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96 RC4-HMAC DES-CBC-CRC DES-CBC-MD5
preferred_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96 RC4-HMAC DES-CBC-CRC DES-CBC-MD5

[realms]
                                                
[domain_relay]

[appdefaults]
    pam = {
        ticket_lifetime = 24h
        renew_lifetime = 7d
        forwardable = true
    }
```

**nsswitch.conf**

```
group: files sss
group_compat: files
hosts: files dns
networks: files
passwd: files sss
passwd_compat: files
shells: files
services: compat
services_compat: files
protocols: files
rpc: files
```

**pam.d/system**

```
# auth
auth            sufficient      pam_opie.so                     no_warn no_fake_prompts
auth            requisite       pam_opieaccess.so               no_warn allow_local
auth            sufficient      pam_unix.so                     no_warn try_first_pass
auth            sufficient      pam_sss.so                      use_first_pass
auth            required        pam_deny.so

# account
account         required        pam_login_access.so
account         required        pam_unix.so
account         sufficient      pam_sss.so

# session
session         required        pam_lastlog.so                  no_fail
account         sufficient      pam_sss.so
session         required        pam_mkhomedir.so                umask=0700

#password
password        required        pam_unix.so                     no_warn try_first_pass nullok use_authtok
password        sufficient      pam_sss.so                      use_authtok
```

**smb4.conf**

```
[global]
 log level = 4
 client signing = yes
 client use spnego = yes

 security = ads
 server string = my-server
 workgroup = DERP
 log file = /var/log/samba4/log.%m
 max log size = 50
 realm = DERP.WHATEVER.COM
 kerberos method = secrets and keytab


[test]
path = /data/test

admin users = @"domain admins"
browseable = yes
create mask = 0775
csc policy = disable
directory mask = 0775
map acl inherit = yes
map archive = No
map readonly = no
nfs4:acedup = merge
nfs4:chown = yes
nfs4:mode = special
nt acl support = yes
posix locking = yes
public = yes
strict locking = no
store dos attributes = yes
vfs objects = zfsacl full_audit
writable = yes

## ACL inheritance is done by ZFS
inherit acls = no
## Avoid chmod(2) that breaks ACL
inherit permissions = no
force create mode = 00000
force directory mode = 00000
store dos attributes = yes
## ZFS ACL implements "write_acl" and "write_owner" permissions that
## is compatible with Windows (NT) ACL better than "dos filemode = yes"
dos filemode = no

full_audit:prefix = %u|%I|%m|%S
full_audit:success = mkdir rename unlink rmdir open close
full_audit:failure = mkdir rename unlink rmdir open close
full_audit:facility = local7
full_audit:priority = NOTICE

veto files = /Thumbs.db/.DS_Store/._.DS_Store/.apdisk/desktop.ini/
```

Comment: Sorry, but you cannot use sssd with Samba >= 4.8.0. sssd uses its own versions of the winbind libs and, if you use 'security = ADS', you must use winbind and sssd and winbind are mutually exclusive.